# load page content using ajax with preloader via select box

Tags: jquery, ajax

Just trying to create a div that we can control its content via ajax load content ( and tag on a preloader just in case )

The fiddle I created is here ( my code is pretty crap. )

http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/Vcwj5/2/

Could someone please explain ..

1. i need to show a specific div ( not the loader gif ) on page load
2. on select choice the content eg. apples.html gets loaded into the div.
3. the loader displays momentarily whilst content is fetched.

Appreciate any help

Cheers Ste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hence all those files exists in the same domain and the path are correct this update of your code will work
http://jsfiddle.net/Vcwj5/9/

Comment: where in this do we trigger loading of the different urls ? aside from the alert you have.. please

Comment: look at the chain command:
1- .html(.....) this adds the preloader
2- .load(loadFile.......) adds the ajax call to load the file

Comment: its ok I sorted it, just noticed i need to add jQuery( function($) { and }); to script

Comment: so .. on page load ( can I load content within the div ( that gets replaced by ajax content ) and when they select nothing ( the null seelction ) that content gets reloaded

Comment: it will be content on the page already called <div class="foo">content</div> so suppose make content hidden if ajax content loaded? Just trying this with php .. as the extension and content doesnt show, have i cocked up something lol

Comment: ok updated http://jsfiddle.net/Vcwj5/12/ i was struggling a bit findind an optimized way of best doing it, this will do

Comment: Cheers @Ady Ngom appreciate your continued help. We still haveing trouble on main site ( I am pretty sure its a z-index issue ) which we will sort, will check out your fiddle. Much appreciated

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7303/discussion-between-ady-ngom-and-422)

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the `<option value="null">--- Please Select---</option>` if you want to preload `apples.html`. make the `apples` as `default` `selected`.

```
<select id="myads" name="ads" style="width: 150px;" class="required">
   <option value="apples.html" selected >apples</option>
   <option value="pears.html">pears</option>
   <option value="carrots.html">carrots</option>
</select>


<div id="adshowblock">

 </div>
<div class="loader" style="display:none;"> // hide this div, it is to use later
    <img src="http://carestream.com/images/ajax-loader.gif"></div>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#adshowblock").html($('.loader').html()); // display loader in div
$("#adshowblock").load("apples.html"); // add this step on document load , loader will be hidden when data is loaded.
$("#myads").change(function(){
     $("#adshowblock").html($('.loader').html());
     $("#adshowblock").load($(this).val());
});
```